# Grails 2.0 cant do run-app &

Tags: grails-2.0

Adding `&`'s to the line where I execute grails seems to be breaking things on any computer I try (so far ubuntu 11.10 and cent 5.something)

Example

```
grails run-app  #works beautiful
nohup grails run-app #works beautiful
grails run-app & # no working :(
```

I get results like this:

```
$ grails run-app &
[3] 16385
$
[3]+  Stopped                 grails run-app
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
( nohup grails run-app --non-interactive 2>&1 > /dev/null & )
```

Thanks to Leighton S. for this.

Comment: Awsome... in my case I needed `
( nohup grails -Duser.timezone=UTC run-app --stacktrace --non-interactive 2>&1 > /dev/null & )`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to fix execution of `grails run-app` in the background is to add this option to you user bashrc/profile:

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="-Djline.terminal=false"
```